# Practicing sentence structure exercises. Did I handle the verbal phrase correctly?

Tags: phrases, verbs, subordinate-clauses

I'm a writer who was never really taught all that soundly the formal aspects of parts of speech. Basic public school education. Was an English major, but we focused on the act of writing moreso than the machinations of the act. I've always written by feel so it's been nice getting into the what and why and when. To that end, I've been developing some craft exercises. One of them involves phrases, clauses, and the like.

I was putting together a sentence that used:

1. Transitional.
2. Prepositional Phrase
3. Verbal Phrase
4. Adjective

This is what I ended up with:

> As a matter of fact, under the hood of the car, there was, to my surprise, a snake, eviscerated, butchered by the dance of the engine.

1. As a matter of fact
2. Under the hood of the car
3. To my surprise
4. Eviscerated

I wasn't sure I had the verbal phrase right. Can it be "there was, to my surprise," with "was" being the verb and "there was" being the verb phrase and "there was, to my surprise" being the verbal phrase?

Or is the "to my surprise" another kind of clause?

Comment: The matrix predicate VP is the entire sentence other than the subject. Can you identify the subject?

Comment: This is pretty much the way [The Chomskybot](https://rubberducky.org/cgi-bin/chomsky.pl) is structured, except the phrases are drawn from lists collected from Chomsky's writings, instead of constructed extemporaneously. [Explanation here.](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/foggy.faq.html)

Comment: @billj The subject would be the snake.

Comment: Hey @JohnLawler! I'm familiar with Chomsky's story but not the details of his work. I looked at the site you linked and saw it mentioned Initiating Phrases, Subject Phrases, Verbal Phrases, and Terminating Phrases. When I googled "Initiating Phrase" nothing came up. Is there a good online resource that gives more info about this? The link on the site just has me download something that can't be opened.

Comment: No, the subject is "there". It's an existential construction with the dummy pronoun "there" as subject. The predicate VP is everything else. Note that the expressions "as a matter of fact" and "under the hood of the car" are adjuncts.

Comment: @CJHLambert: Those are not grammatical terms; those are file labels. The Chomskybot is satirical in nature and intent; I was commenting on the way you put sentences together, at the phrase level. That's good; phrases are constituents and constituents are everything in syntax.

Comment: @BillJ, sorry I'm getting to this a year later. What sentence would you construct with the initial prompt I was using? Would be good to see an example!